# Finding the distance between 'Doctag' and 'infer_vector' with Gensim Doc2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

Using Gensim's Doc2Vec how would I find the distance between a `Doctag` and an `infer_vector()`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Doctag` is the internal name for the keys to doc-vectors. The result of an `infer_vector()` operation is a vector. So as you've literally asked, these aren't comparable.

You could ask a model for a known doc-vector, by its doc-tag key that was supplied during training, via `model.docvecs[doctag]`. That would be comparable to the result of an `infer_vector()` call.

With two vectors in hand, you can use `scipy` routines to calculate various kinds of distance. For example:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance.cosine as cosine_distance
vec_by_doctag = model.docvecs["doc0007"]
vec_by_inference = model.infer_vector(['a', 'cat', 'was', 'in', 'a', 'hat'])
dist = cosine_distance(vec_by_doctag, vec_by_inference)
```

You can also look at how gensim's `Doc2VecKeyedVectors` does similarity/distance between vectors that are known (by their doctag key names) inside a model, in its `similarity()` and `distance()` functions, at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ca0dcaa1eca8b1764f6456adac5719309e0d8e6d/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1701

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ca0dcaa1eca8b1764f6456adac5719309e0d8e6d/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1743

Comment: Cheers for providing a solution and the extra references at the end! :)